# Datetime glitching out on two completely arbitrary dates

Tags: python, datetime, web-scraping, wikipedia

I'm working on a code to scrape data on NBA players age straight from Wikipedia, pretty much finished it some days ago, returned to it today to check if it's working, whole code looks like this (I've added try/except statement in *yyyy_mm_dd_to_age* function and commented out the extra code that works fine):

```
import bs4
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
import statistics
import datetime as dt
from typing import Generator, Tuple, List, T
def tables_by_class(soup: bs4.BeautifulSoup,
                    html_class: str) -> Generator[pd.DataFrame, None, None]:
    tables = soup.find_all("table", {"class": html_class})
    tables = pd.read_html(str(tables))
    for table in tables:
        yield table
def divs_by_id(soup: bs4.BeautifulSoup,
               html_id: str) -> bs4.element.ResultSet:
    elements = soup.find_all("div", {"id": html_id})
    return elements
def yyyy_mm_dd_to_age(b_date: str) -> float:
    try:
        b_date = dt.datetime.strptime(b_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
        today = dt.date.today()
        today = dt.datetime(year = today.year,
                            month = today.month,
                            day = today.day)
        return round((today - b_date).days / 365.25, 2)
    except ValueError:
        return b_date
def l_flatten(l: List[T]) -> List[T]:
    return [j for i in l for j in i]
def l_to_bins(l: List[float],
              bins: List[float]) -> List[float]:
    pairs = {(i, j): 0 for i, j in zip(bins, bins[1:])}
    for pair in pairs:
        pairs[pair] += len([i for i in l if pair[0] < i <= pair[1]])
    return pairs
def team_data():
    url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_NBA_team_rosters"
    html_content = requests.get(url).text
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
    team_names = divs_by_id(soup, "toc")[0]
    team_names = team_names.find_all("a", href = True)
    words_out = ["Conference", "Division", "See", "References", "External"]
    team_names = [i["href"][1:] for i in team_names
                  if not any(j in i["href"] for j in words_out)]
    team_tables = tables_by_class(soup, "sortable")
    team_tables = [table["DOB (YYYY-MM-DD)"].tolist() for table in team_tables]
    team_tables = [[yyyy_mm_dd_to_age(b_date) for b_date in table]
                   for table in team_tables]
    return team_tables
    # this is necessary, but i commented it out to figure out the bug
    #team_tables = [sorted(table) for table in team_tables]
    #age_dict = {name: table for name, table in zip(team_names, team_tables)}
    #age_dict = dict(sorted(age_dict.items()))
    #age_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(list(age_dict.values()),
    #                             index = list(age_dict.keys()))
    #age_dist = l_flatten(age_dataframe.values.tolist())
    #age_dist = l_to_bins(age_dist, [i for i in np.linspace(18, 42, 9)])
    #return age_dataframe, age_dist
data = team_data()
print(data)
```

The output is this:

```
[[27.56, 24.97, 23.17, 23.85, 26.05, 35.37, 29.4, 21.97, 24.97, 24.5, 22.0, 26.42, 25.94, 23.71, 28.08, 28.08, 27.61, 23.62, 22.87, 23.99], [36.24, 27.28, '1997–01–20', 25.17, 25.02, 26.09, 22.5, 22.01, 33.04, 21.18, 22.28, 32.58, 32.14, 30.11, 29.56, 34.65, 33.18, 36.68, '1999–09–30', 19.94, 20.01, 23.2], [21.34, 30.24, 28.96, 36.31, 26.04, 21.44, 22.18, 21.1, 27.52, 22.33, 26.88, 23.54, 33.03, 27.04, 22.66, 22.99, 23.62, 31.44, 23.55], [20.96, 31.15, 28.18, 27.58, 34.32, 29.25, 28.02, 22.13, 22.29, 24.23, 21.03, 25.05, 28.33, 22.31, 24.68, 25.24, 19.06, 24.62], [22.07, 24.25, 21.94, 20.21, 29.05, 21.94, 28.76, 20.3, 27.44, 35.44, 23.43, 20.63, 24.35, 27.54, 22.74, 27.64, 27.09, 27.01], [23.97, 23.21, 22.22, 27.63, 24.06, 32.19, 21.74, 22.2, 28.23, 25.48, 25.38, 24.66, 26.6, 22.0, 27.2, 30.98, 21.66, 20.14], [23.49, 23.29, 25.85, 21.72, 24.18, 33.1, 24.4, 20.33, 22.57, 20.72, 26.52, 28.72, 30.98, 22.78, 24.27, 27.91, 24.9, 25.06], [22.52, 20.05, 30.4, 23.21, 22.8, 27.59, 20.22, 23.45, 24.68, 30.15, 22.31, 23.22, 25.94, 30.21, 30.49, 23.81, 21.81, 22.16, 20.4, 26.54], [22.24, 23.32, 28.84, 29.56, 24.34, 22.35, 32.53, 19.76, 23.73, 29.38, 27.14, 26.2, 29.56, 25.45, 27.79, 22.06, 25.56, 32.22, 28.11, 21.56], [26.02, 26.86, 29.24, 26.49, 28.77, 23.52, 24.7, 35.45, 31.34, 28.99, 22.78, 33.54, 22.4, 30.18, 23.1, 28.37, 26.86, 26.68, 24.01, 23.76], [29.16, 27.41, 24.06, 20.34, 31.74, 33.19, 27.7, 30.58, 23.13, 23.87, 22.13, 19.82, 26.44, 24.11, 25.83, 20.84, 22.12, 34.97, 29.47, 23.07], [20.15, 21.07, 23.57, 20.64, 22.25, 31.56, 26.82, 20.74, 23.78, 21.59, 26.05, 23.7, 24.04, 25.85, 31.61, 23.88, 27.58, 33.28, 19.14, 23.15], [24.24, 32.08, 32.18, 22.93, 41.35, 21.74, 35.56, 26.05, 32.12, 22.47, 27.45, 23.53, 27.48, 22.37, 23.79, 22.22, 25.55, 36.45, 25.34, 23.32], [21.42, 23.43, 22.77, 22.5, 30.02, 24.43, 23.38, 25.25, 20.68, 27.09, 24.03, 33.54, 32.64, 23.16, 30.69, 24.54, 20.37, 22.89, 20.13, 24.47], [20.78, 28.3, 28.92, 24.21, 28.65, 28.53, 24.47, 23.04, 28.99, 22.98, 23.68, 27.72, 25.04, 23.14, 22.62, 26.23, 29.41, 23.34, 19.99, 23.63], [30.77, 21.9, 21.91, 30.57, 24.51, 26.22, 24.97, 26.08, 31.32, 35.13, 22.62, 21.08, 26.65, 26.3, 24.64, 20.76, 23.3, 26.35, 29.2, 24.5], [24.88, 33.26, 21.09, 23.04, 20.19, 24.07, 27.61, 22.82, 21.04, 25.52, 22.93, 22.27, 23.12, 27.57, 22.14, 25.64, 25.07, 25.92, 22.54, 22.97], [21.34, 26.68, 24.73, 22.49, 30.25, 19.01, 23.26, 24.27, 21.32, 20.34, 20.7, 30.29, 19.8, 20.95, 23.7, 26.79, 22.78, 26.87], [25.89, 20.12, 24.29, 28.56, 30.84, 21.33, 31.25, 21.68, 30.07, 28.67, 28.79, 27.15, 32.59, 28.39, 22.35, 23.89, 29.93, 20.93, 29.03], [24.08, 22.08, 32.49, 23.5, 21.14, 29.36, 34.01, 24.28, 23.34, 35.16, 29.3, 23.6, 34.04, 25.1, 28.36, 24.2, 24.94, 24.34, 32.34], [26.77, 33.43, 30.89, 25.89, 33.59, 31.62, 37.71, 19.03, 28.98, 25.69, 19.38, 27.34, 28.87, 22.32, 28.37, 31.68, 28.51, 26.64, 20.54], [32.84, 31.85, 19.88, 24.33, 31.46, 23.48, 23.45, 32.07, 31.5, 19.6, 25.31, 27.75, 30.3, 24.99, 32.12, 22.18, 21.12, 25.56, 22.81, 24.58], [37.38, 36.29, 21.61, 32.29, 22.86, 28.6, 20.81, 33.88, 20.89, 35.85, 36.79, 33.23, 22.77, 23.69, 26.2, 25.26, 24.64, 23.38, 35.64, 32.92], [23.23, 24.96, 25.13, 31.28, 25.47, 25.62, 28.53, 33.74, 28.05, 36.44, 27.19, 27.64, 28.69, 27.52, 24.59, 21.58], [22.59, 29.38, 23.73, 24.42, 23.82, 21.63, 28.43, 28.83, 28.0, 26.29, 22.53, 28.33, 24.57, 23.11, 22.26, 20.35, 20.04, 25.15, 30.59, 22.09], [22.01, 26.68, 25.12, 30.58, 28.92, 28.16, 22.63, 28.45, 20.91, 29.58, 22.28, 23.81, 29.71, 33.17, 23.71, 23.22, 24.67, 26.2, 30.24, 21.05], [33.93, 23.68, 23.36, 19.85, 26.26, 19.6, 32.8, 19.68, 28.36, 23.73, 20.77, 19.67, 28.75, 21.45, 19.23, 25.97, 29.53, 31.11, 26.05], [28.24, 20.76, 28.07, 23.31, 25.73, 25.07, 22.65, 27.58, 22.08, 25.43, 25.57, 24.95, 23.38, 25.42, 22.18, 22.39, 23.61, 22.76, 20.35, 20.09], [23.12, 23.51, 23.75, 24.56, 26.64, 26.61, 21.4, 27.39, 25.97, 25.28, 24.12, 23.03, 20.53, 22.29, 23.72, 21.33, 29.96, 35.44, 29.44, 21.28], [31.07, 25.73, 23.9, 24.7, 28.23, 22.01, 21.77, 25.97, 29.78, 25.07, 26.0, 18.81, 21.14, 22.84, 27.29, 22.15, 33.32]]
```

As you see, all the dates have been successfully converted to age except for two, and I've been going crazy trying to figure it out. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: What do you mean by "as you see"? What should we see? You haven't indicated any specific errors. You can't expect everyone to run your code.

Comment: Ah, I totally forgot, my bad. So sorry, will fix it all now.

Comment: BTW there appears to be a [Python package](https://towardsdatascience.com/wikipedia-api-for-python-241cfae09f1c) for scraping Wikipedia. Not sure how useful or up to date it is, but may be helpful. Also note that scraping web pages is fragile and often a [questionable practice](https://towardsdatascience.com/ethics-in-web-scraping-b96b18136f01).

Comment: Yes, absolutely, I'm aware. Basically it's like only one page and one request a time, so yeah, no worries here.

Comment: The root cause of your problem was `except ValueError: return b_date`. The code doesn't log or report the error and the function doesn't  return a consistent value because `b_date` could be either a string or a datetime depending on where the error occurred. Moral: don't pass silently over errors, especially not in code under development.

Comment: I've done that on purpose, since if I removed the try/except block, it would just not work, but yeah, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some of the date time format does not using hyphen `"-"` as separator

they are using `"–"`

try change your `dt.datetime.strptime(b_date, "%Y-%m-%d")` to `try_datetime(b_date)`

and it may work

```
def try_datetime(b_date: str) -> dt.datetime:
    try:
        return dt.datetime.strptime(b_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
    except:
        return dt.datetime.strptime(b_date, "%Y–%m–%d")
```